# Difference between 040 and 40

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a new Python programmer, and stumbled on to this seeming anomaly --

```
>>> line = input()
40
>>> print line*3
120
>>> line = input()
040
>>> print line*3
96
```

What caused this deviation? Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 7):

`040` is an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) integer literal. It has a value of **0***8<sup>2</sup> + **4***8<sup>1</sup> + **0***8<sup>0</sup> == **32**. Hence, when you multiply it by 3, the result is 96.

The grammar of integer literals in Python 2.x is given in the section [2.4.4. Integer and long integer literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) of the language reference.

Thanks to @JonClements for pointing out that `040` is only valid in Python 2.x, and invalid in 3.x (see the comments below).

Comment: Might be worth noting that that's only the case for Py 2.x, `040` is an invalid literal in Python3.x (it'd need to be 0o040 for eg) - but then its `input` isn't the same anyway...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, I made a note of that.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2.x parses `040` as an octal number. Now, it may be true that the only reason for octal numbers these days is to confuse programmers who started less than twenty years ago, but it is a matter of fact that we still have them …

Comment: +1 I don't think there was enough use for them 20 years ago to give them their own literal format either... :)